# Testing anOrdered Collection

Tags: collections, smalltalk, pharo

```
|email addressList|
email:= '<abc@gmail.com>,abcd ,<abcef@domail.com>'.
addressList:= MailAddressParser addressesIn:email.
```

Above code will get me an Ordered collection which will include all the strings, though 'abcd' is not a valid email id its still there in collection.

My question is how can i remove Invalid email address which don't include '@'.

```
addressList do[:ele | " How can i check each item if it includes @ , if not remove it."]
```

Comment: You are aware that abcd is a valid email-address? It could refer to a user on the current machine. It is just not fully qualified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take several approaches:

Do exactly what you've asked for (deleting from the existing collection)

```
addressList removeAllSuchThat: [:string| (string includes: $@) not ]
```

Or you can generate a new list that includes only the valid elements like Uko proposed. Here you exchange addressList with the new list.

```
addressList select: [:string| string includes: $@ ]
```

Or you can generate a new list that excludes the invalid elements

```
addressList reject: [:string| (string includes: $@) not ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
addressList select: [ :email | email includes: $@ ]
```

if you're looking just for one character like `@` (as was suggested by @dh82), or if you'll need to look for a substring you can use:

```
addressList select: [ :email | email includesSubString: '@' ]
```

`select:` creates a new collection that with the elements that match the condition specified in a block.